# Django Rest Framework generics CreateAPIView - how to just include foreign key, without creating one

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to make a generics.CreateAPIView, per the DRF documentation.

I have this (I can include my PageSerializer if it would be helpful:

```
class PageCreateView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    queryset = Page.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PageSerializer
```

Here is my model:

```
class Page(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField("Post date")
    intro = models.CharField(max_length=600)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    chinese = models.TextField(blank=True)
    english = models.TextField(blank=True)
    json = JSONField(default=dict, null=True, blank=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(
        Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    calculated_hsk = models.DecimalField(
        default=1, max_digits=3, decimal_places=2)
    translated = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

I am trying to use the POST endpoint, however when I have a POST request like this:

```
    {
        "translated": true,
        "category": 1,
        "title": "Test POST title",
        "english": "Test English Text",
        "chinese": "我是一个兵",
        "intro": "test intro",
        "date": "2020-08-02",
        "calculated_hsk": 3.5,
        "json": {
       }
    }
```

I get the following error:

```
{
    "category": {
        "non_field_errors": [
            "Invalid data. Expected a dictionary, but got int."
        ]
    }
}
```

When I try to put it inside a dict, I get requests for fields for the category, which is a totally separate table.

I have zero desire to create a new category entry every time I create a new page - I just want to associate the page with the category.

How do I do that?

Serializers:

```
class CategorySerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    name = serializers.CharField()
    id = serializers.IntegerField()

class PageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    category = CategorySerializer(many=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Page
        fields = ['date', 'intro', "chinese", "english",
                  "calculated_hsk", "translated", "json", "id", "category", "title"]
```

Comment: Can you include your serializers?

Comment: Added them above

Comment: I think you'll have to create another `Page` serializer that you use for the create API that doesn't use a nested serializer for category

Comment: @IainShelvington How will I create the association to the category table then? Like I want to have the relationship initialized when I create the page.

Comment: I think you would use a `PrimaryKeyRelatedField` https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#primarykeyrelatedfield

Comment: Yep! That worked. I replaced my category reference in my serializer to:     category = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        many=False, queryset=Category.objects.all()) and everything worked great